# Java Regex for "," but not ", "

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string str "A,B,C,[D, E, F]" and I'm trying to split it such that my resulting string array would contain the elements "A", "B", "C" and "[D, E, F]".
But, when I run `str.split(",")`, the string array contains "A", "B", "C", "[D", " E", and " F]".
What regex should I use for the split to resolve this?

Comment: You can use `match` instead of `split` with the regex `/\[.*?]|[^,]+/`

Comment: What is expected output for `A, B,C,D, [ E,F, G, H]`? Note the spaces before commas outside of square brackets and inside square brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to ignore commas followed by a space

```
str.split(",(?! )")
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to split with/out space. OP wants to handle string wrapped in square brackets differently.

Comment: @Tushar The ones in the brackets have spaces. Look at the question title.

Comment: Yep. Worked like a charm. Thanks, shmosel.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: Derived from Tushar's comment above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "A,B,C,[D, E, F]";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?]|[A-Z]+").matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```